# How can I maximize my chances to win a battle using Auto-Resolve?

Tags: medieval-2-total-war

Medieval 2: Total War has an "auto-resolve" feature like many of its predecessors, which I use almost exclusively.  However, it's not exactly obvious what contributes to my chances of success.  The factors I've identified are:

- Number of Troops
- Type of Troops (Spearman are better than Peasants, etc)
- Command rating of commander

What other factors figure into the "Auto-Resolve" feature?  How can I maximize these factors to give me the best chance of winning?  Is there anything I would do differently compared to manually playing out the battles?

Comment: The best way to win battles is really to not leave it to auto resolve. Auto resolve almost always works in the AI's favor, since the real time battle AI is poor enough that even the most mediocre human player can outperform it. Besides, you're arguably missing out on half the game by not playing out the battles in person.

Comment: @YiJiang'sEvilClone I know all that, but I just don't have the hours it takes to play through the battles.  I enjoy the battles, but I like to finish a campaign in less than a year.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest factors are:

- The number of troops
- The quality of troops (attack, defense, health, experience, equipment level)
- The types of troops used versus other types (archer vs. sword, spear vs. cavalry, etc.)
- Command rating of leading general
- Terrain bonus for applicable units
- Morale level of unit (weaker units tend to have low morale and some abilities lower an enemy units morale)
- A random chance roll that mimics the luck factor

The best way to maximize success is to use massive armies and use a variety of troops suited for the faction you are fighting (fight their strengths with troops that are strong against that type).